# Why Debug.log prints out in reversed order in Elm?

Tags: elm

Consider this program:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Debug


main : Element
main =
  let
    one = Debug.log "one" 1
    two = Debug.log "two" 2
    three = Debug.log "three" 3
  in
    show "Hello"
```

It prints out the following to browser's console:

```
three: 3
two: 2
one: 1
```

Why is the order reversed?

Comment: A let clause is not a list of instructions but a set of declarations, the compiler is free to determine their "execution order". In general, when programming functionally, you typically do not have to bother with execution order but the relationship of concepts and data.

Answer (score 30):

```all
main =
  let
    one = Debug.log "one" 1
    two = Debug.log "two" 2
    three = Debug.log "three" 3
  in
    show "Hello"
```

Actually gets compiled down to

```js
var main = function () {
  var three = A2($Debug.log,
  "three",
  3);
  var two = A2($Debug.log,
  "two",
  2);
  var one = A2($Debug.log,
  "one",
  1);
  return $Graphics$Element.show("Hello");
}();
```

Notice how the order seems to be flipped. If we introduce another value which is dependent on something else in the let binding, the following happens instead:

```all
 main =
   let
     one = Debug.log "one" 1
     two = Debug.log "two" 2
     three = Debug.log "three" 3
     four = Debug.log "four" three + one
   in
     show "Hello"
```

turns into

```js
var main = function () {
  var three = A2($Debug.log,
  "three",
  3);
  var two = A2($Debug.log,
  "two",
  2);
  var one = A2($Debug.log,
  "one",
  1);
  var four = A2($Debug.log,
  "four",
  three) + one;
  return $Graphics$Element.show("Hello");
}();
```

The long and short of it therefore is that values which aren't dependant on another value in the same scope get processed bottom-up. When a value relies on another value within the same scope, it is handled separately and put at the bottom.

This is an implementation detail.

Comment: An excellent answer for "why does this happen". To answer "why should I care": don't. It's an impure function; it breaks the rules.